# PHP - Read from a file and generate corresponding radio button

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a fee management system project, what I want to do is, whenever a student logs into his account, he needs to select a subject for which he has to pay fee, the subjects are stored in a subjects.txt file which is not static, I mean, the administrator has the right to add a subject into that file, so I cannot simply create radio buttons with pre-specified values.
The file structure is like:

```
    subject_id|subject_fee|subject|name
```

What I managed to do is to display the student, the list of subject_id's and subject_name and also his own id.
Here is the code for that:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $user_details[0] = $_SESSION['temp0'];
    echo"The subject id and corresponding subject name are <br>";
    $sub_id = file ('subjects.txt');
    foreach ($sub_id as $subject_id) {
           $sub_id = explode('|', $subject_id);
           echo $sub_id[0].'--->'.$sub_id[2]."<br>";
    }
    echo'Your id is '.$user_details[0];
    ?>
```

Is this possible, or should I just ask the student to read the subject_name and id and take an input of that in a text field. This will work just fine for me, but it would be better to use radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the "subject" field in the radio button, I think you should use `$sub_id[2]`. 
What would work is adding a code that gives every radio button the name `$sub_id[0]` for the subject ID and the display text to be `$sub_id[2]`, which is apparently the **display subject name**.
So, inside the `foreach`, at the end, add the code:

```
<?php
echo ('<form action="..." method="...">');
echo ('<input type="radio" name="$sub_id[0]" value="$sub_id[2] /> $sub_id[2] <br>');
echo ('</form>');
?>
```

You could use labels for the HTML. The radio button code was taken from [w3schools Tryit](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio).

Comment: I didn't knew that I can create a form using echo also!

Comment: But, it's giving an error, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\FMS1\temp_student_fee.php on line 23" for the echo('</form>');

Comment: Make sure everything is nested properly, it might be a problem where the whole code hadn't been copied. And: `echo` just outputs text into the document. You can use it to output HTML, CSS... everything.